# Why JSON pretty print is not working?

Tags: java, json, spring, jackson, pretty-print

I am trying to do the same thing as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10532217/jax-rs-json-pretty-output), but I've tried every possibility I found and I could not make it work.

So far, I have this code:

```
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
//import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

import org.jboss.resteasy.annotations.providers.jaxb.json.BadgerFish;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationFeature;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializationFeature;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.annotation.JacksonFeatures;

@Path(value = "/mock")
@Controller
public class MockController {

    @BadgerFish
    @GET
    @Path(value = "/get")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    @JacksonFeatures(serializationEnable = {SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT})
    public Container getMockedContainer() {
        return newContainer();
    }

    @BadgerFish
    @GET
    @Path(value = "/getXML")
    @Produces(value = MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE)
    public Container getMockedContainerXML() {
        return newContainer();
    }

    //MORE CODE HERE
}
```

I can go to `http://localhost:8081/containerMocked/mock/getXML/` and get the expected XML output, easy. But when I try `localhost/.../get/` I get the correct data but not pretty printed.

At least to me, `@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)` and `@JacksonFeatures(serializationEnable =  { SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT})` should be enough.

What am I doing wrong?

**DISCLAIMER:** I will not put here what `newContainer()` does as it involves too many classes. The thing you must understand is that this `Main`

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws javax.xml.bind.JAXBException {
    Container container = new MockController().newContainer();
    final javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext jaxbContext = javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(Container.class);
    javax.xml.bind.Marshaller marshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();
    marshaller.setProperty(javax.xml.bind.Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, Boolean.TRUE);
    marshaller.marshal(container, System.out);
}
```

Will output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<container>
    <leaf>
        <id>int32</id>
        <possibleValues/>
        <type>int32</type>
        <value>2147483647</value>
    </leaf>
    <id>device</id>
</container>
```

and `http://localhost:8081/containerMocked/mock/get/` will output:

```
{"container":{"leaf":{"id":{"$":"int32"},"possibleValues":{},"type":{"$":"int32"},"value":{"$":"2147483647"}},"id":{"$":"device"}}}
```

**EDIT:** I have just tested `@Formatted` annotation according to [this link](https://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/3.0.9.Final/userguide/html/json.html#Jackson_JSON_Decorator) and I also got no results.

Why these annotations are not working, but `@Produces` and `@BadgerFish` work normally for example?

I would prefer to do it in the most simple way if possible. And for me, the most simple way is make one of the above annotations work as expected.

Comment: FYI, you can omit `get` in your paths. The HTTP verb will communicate that information.

Comment: It just there because I already got the project with that annotation on. I'll try without it.

Answer (score 1):

You could try registering an ObjectMapper provider with your JAX-RS implementation:

```
@Provider
public class ObjectMapperProvider implements ContextResolver<ObjectMapper> {

    @Override
    public ObjectMapper getContext(Class<?> aClass) {
        return new ObjectMapper().enable(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT);
    }
}
```

Comment: I've tried to implement something simillar to the answer of the question I've mentioned which base on what you said, but I think I not sure how to implement it correctly. I saw some examples of `ObjectMapper` but I have never use it, how I will pass my data to it?

Comment: @PatrickBard looks like you are using RESTEasy? If so, RE will handle it for you behind the scenes when Container (or any Java object) is translated in to a response body.