# WildFly 10 NoDefClassFound com/fasterxml/jackson/jaxrs/cfg/ObjectWriterModifier

Tags: json, jackson, wildfly, pretty-print, wildfly-10

To ease developing my endpoints returning JSON, I want to enable prettyprinting.

The [solution I'm tyring to implement](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32649532/1336263) is adding a filter that injects an ObjectWriterModifier enabling the default pretty printer, if the query string is ?pretty=1.

Deployment fails as it cannot find the class `com/fasterxml/jackson/jaxrs/cfg/ObjectWriterModifier`

which is contained in `jackson-jaxrs-base-2.7.4.jar` under `modules/system/layer/base/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jaxrs/jackson-jaxrs-json-provider` of my WildFly 10 installation.

In my build.gradle I do specify the dependicy as provided:

```
dependencies {
    providedCompile 'javax:javaee-api:7.0'
    providedCompile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.7.4'
    providedCompile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.7.4'
    providedCompile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs:jackson-jaxrs-json-provider:2.7.4'
}
```

Here is module.xml for jackson-jaxrs-json-provider

```
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.3" name="com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.jackson-jaxrs-json-provider">
     <resources>
        <resource-root path="jackson-jaxrs-json-provider-2.7.4.jar"/>
        <resource-root path="jackson-jaxrs-base-2.7.4.jar"/>
        <resource-root path="jackson-module-jaxb-annotations-2.7.4.jar"/>
    </resources>

    <dependencies>
        <module name="javax.api"/>
        <module name="javax.ws.rs.api"/>
        <module name="javax.xml.bind.api"/>
        <module name="com.fasterxml.jackson.core.jackson-annotations"/>
        <module name="com.fasterxml.jackson.core.jackson-core"/>
        <module name="com.fasterxml.jackson.core.jackson-databind"/>
    </dependencies>
</module>
```

**I don't see how WildFly can't find a class that's inside one of the jars it provides**

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the [class loading documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY10/Class+Loading+in+WildFly). You may need to add a module dependency as all modules aren't just automatically added as a dependency to deployments.