# JAX-RS Json response comes in one line

Tags: json, jax-rs

This is probably some basic question. I am using JAX-RS (jersey implementation) and my code is as follows.

```
@Path("/data")
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Car handlerFn(@Context HttpServletResponse res)
{
    res.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);

    Car carObject = new Car(42,"Maruthi", "Alto");
    return carObject;
}
```

Car Entity is as follows

```
public class Car {

int id;
String name;
String model;

public Car() {

}

public Car(int id, String name, String model)
{
    this.id=id;
    this.name = name;
    this.model = model;
}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public String getModel() {
    return model;
}
}
```

The output I am getting is in one line as follows

```
{"id":42,"model":"Alto","name":"Maruthi"}
```

In place of this I want the each member in different lines as follows

```
{
  "id": 42,
  "model": "Alto",
  "name": "Maruthi"

}
```

How can I do that?

Comment: may I know why you want to do it ? You can use @JacksonFeatures(serializationEnable =  { SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT }) as stated in here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10532217/jax-rs-json-pretty-output

Comment: This is common behaviour. Every browser or request sender (like Insomnia) shows the JSON formatted in some way. There is really no need to output this in a human readable form.

Comment: I need a human readable output for two of the URLs in my project so that users can see in the standard documented format. Is it adding @JacksonFeatures(serializationEnable =  { SerializationConfig.INDENT_OUTPUT })  for the above methods is sufficient? I am getting "The value for annotation attribute JacksonFeatures.serializationEnable must be an enum constant expression" error while doing it.

Comment: The error has gone when I used the following import.  import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializationFeature;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.annotation.JacksonFeatures.. But the output is same. Do I am missing something?